# If mobile BERT model requires DataType.INT32, is it possible to run on Android as a tensorflow lite model?

Tags: android, nlp, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-lite, bert-language-model

I am trying to run [mobile BERT model](https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/mobilebert_multi_cased_L-24_H-128_B-512_A-4_F-4_OPT/1) on Android and have several issues with this.

After converting model into `tflite`, format I am able to load it into Android Studio over ML binding. However, if I launch sample usage code shown after adding this model, I will get compiler error regarding unsupported `DataType.INT32` type.

Looking further in code I have found just two supported types:

```
    public static @NonNull TensorBuffer createFixedSize(@NonNull int[] shape, DataType dataType) {
        switch (dataType) {
            case FLOAT32:
                return new TensorBufferFloat(shape);
            case UINT8:
                return new TensorBufferUint8(shape);
            default:
                throw new AssertionError("TensorBuffer does not support data type: " + dataType);
        }
    }
```

(package org.tensorflow.lite.**support**.*)

However, [Tensorflow **Lite** docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/api_docs/java/org/tensorflow/lite/DataType) shows the framework supports this `DataType.INT32` type.

Further research shown there are two `tf lite` packages which could be used on Android:

```
    implementation("org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:2.13.0")
    implementation("org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-support:0.4.4")
```

Android Studio automatically import `org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-support:0.4.4` but not a `org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:2.13.0`. I haven't found information about difference between them.

It is also possible to use more lower level API to build a model with a different types:

```
        val input = mutableListOf<Any>()
        input.add(TensorBuffer.createFixedSize(intArrayOf(1, masTextLength), DataType.INT32))
        input.add(TensorBuffer.createFixedSize(intArrayOf(1, masTextLength), DataType.INT32))
        input.add(TensorBuffer.createFixedSize(intArrayOf(1, masTextLength), DataType.INT32))
        val output = ""
        interpreter!!.run(input, output)
```

, but I am not sure it would be correct to use `UINT8` or `FLOAT32` types instead of `INT32`

The questions are:

If mobile BERT model requires DataType.INT32, is it possible to run on Android as a tensorflow lite model?

If we have to use `Interpreter` to import a model, how input and output should look like?